# PYTHON ERROR '2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)' while creating SQL database

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

Wrote a code to create a sql database via Python:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
def create_connection(host_name, user_name, user_password):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host_name,
            user=user_name,
            passwd=user_password
        )
        print("Connection to MySQL DB successful")
    except Error as e:
        print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")
    return connection

connection = create_connection("localhost", "phpmyadmin","mhldb2022!")
```

But I get an error message:

```
The error '2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)' occurred
```

In order for the database to be created in phpMyAdmin, I installed WAMP.

Access to phpMyAdmin :

```
localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

(default login is "root", no password).

Could you help me to solve the problem?
I really can't understand what is wrong here.

Comment: Have you *actually* installed MySQL? PHPMyAdmin is *not* MySQL, and neither is SQL Server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.